# Rx: Where are the WindowWithTime, WindowWithCount operators?

Tags: system.reactive

I see these mentioned all over the web; however, they don't seem to exist when I import the latest Rx via NuGet.  Were these methods renamed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're all overloads of `Window` now:

```
var maxWindowCount = 5;

.Window(maxWindowCount)
.Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
```

Lee Campbell has a good article on `Window`, `GroupJoin` and `Buffer`:
http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2011/03/rx-part-9join-window-buffer-and-group.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I loved Lee Campbell's e-book - I read the whole thing.  The only thing I didn't clearly get from it were how to do moving averages (overlapping windows, essentially).  I had to write my own extension method, but I've never been sure that it's the best implementation!

Comment: @blaster Yeah, overlapping windows is by far the trickiest thing to pull off properly; I *always* screw them up the first time I write them...